# WPAllImport: multiple attributes per product in different nodes

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

In the xml to be imported each node has a SKU, a characteristic label and its value. A SKU has multiple characteristics so there are multiple nodes for the same SKU. I want to add the characteristics in the description field of each matched product. But I don't know how I can append each characteristic to a new line every time a product is matched by the sku. And how I can delete the description in the first occurence of the SKU in order not to have huge repititive description...

Here is a part of the xml:

```
<chars>
  <product>SKU1</product>
  <atribute>Label1</atribute>
  <value>Value1</value>
</chars>
<chars>
  <product>SKU1</product>
  <atribute>Label2</atribute>
  <value>Value2</value>
</chars>
<chars>
  <product>SKU2</product>
  <atribute>Label21</atribute>
  <value>Value21</value>
</chars>
<chars>
  <product>SKU3</product>
  <atribute>Label31</atribute>
  <value>Value31</value>
</chars>
<chars>
  <product>SKU3</product>
  <atribute>Label32</atribute>
  <value>Value32</value>
</chars>
<chars>....</chars>
```

Given this example I want product with SKU1's description:
Label1:Value1
Label2:Value2 etc.

Comment: I guess you should follow the method to update data in already existing posts, https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/update-existing-posts/ (assuming that will work "during" an import as well, and not only for posts that existed before the current run started already.)

Comment: If I update the data then the description will be overwritter and not appended... And if I manage to append it then in another run of the import it want delete the existing but it will keep appending endesly

Comment: You could use the function editor to create yourself a little function that fetches the current description of the post first, and concatenates that with the new value from the current node. (Likely going to slow down the import process though.) And you could use the `pmxi_before_xml_import` hook to empty the description for all posts before the actual import starts ...